# Why does std::thread require 'this' when called on a member function?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

When calling std::thread from within my Class on a member function I have to pass 'this' as my first parameter.

If I don't I get a fat wall of errors when I compile.

Why is 'this' required?

```
threads[i] = std::thread(&ClName::thread_exec, this);
```

The above is a snippet of the code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every member function receives a hidden argument, `this`, which points to the actual object. Theres only a single method code in the binary, it is object agnostic (but not class agnostic). You have to tell them which object they have to work on.

Comment: I see. So basically, all of my member functions recieve 'this' implicitly, but because std::thread() is not a member function, it needs the object reference passed through explicitly?

Comment: Almost. The constructor of std::thread expects a function pointer, and calls it. Since it expects that hidden this, you have to provide one.